# Infinite loop with while and for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

my program ends in infinite loop how can i make this work?

```
number=0
while number!=4:
     for i in range(10):
           number+=1
```

I want it to end when the number equals 4
Thanks for the help

Comment: why are you using `while` and `for` together for this? You just need any one of these. Also, logic of your code will depend on the initial value of `number` which you haven't mentioned here

Comment: it is a part of more complicated program the number is set to zero at the begining

Comment: In case you do not know, your `for` loop will be executed completely before the control goes back to `while`. So after first complete execution of `for`, value of number will be `1+2...+10` which is not equal to `4` and it is continuously increasing. Hence, `number !=4` will always be true

Comment: I think you need to check a tutorial on loops. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I understand why this doesn't work. But I need to make it somehow work,  because there are more things programmed in the forloop in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
number=0
while number!=4:
    number+=10
```

Which means `number!=4` will always be true.

I believe what you want is this:

```
number=0
while number!=4:
    number+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition (`number!=4`) for the while loop isn't checked until the for loop finishes executing, in which case if `number` is initially 0, will be 10, therefore not 4:

```
number=0
while number!=4:
     for i in range(10):
           number+=1
```

You can add a condition inside the for loop to break when it reaches four. I don't think you need the for loop at all given your code segment, this will do the same (stop when `number` reaches 4):

```
number=0
while number<4:
    number+=1
```